# Reputation misrepresented on chat profile pages

Tags: feature-request, chat

I am looking at my [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/36486/obsessivefoss) and see that it misrepresents my reputation, as my "[parent user](https://askubuntu.com/users/54298/obsessivefoss)" has about 600-700rep. This total should ignore sites with less that 200 rep to avoid skewing these measurements with easy association bonuses.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is the total for all.

Comment: But wouldn't that inflate users' rep with the assoc bonus? It would be fairer to remove the assoc bonus in the calculation.

Comment: So you want it to be the same as in [your global flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1394089.png)? If so please explain this in the question and remove the *bug* tag leaving it as feature request.

Comment: The global flair ignores sites with < 200 rep. The chat total includes all sites. This will explain the difference.